# How to toggle hide imageView from subclassing UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a subclass of UIButton and it have an initialiser that accept a name and boolean. I have a function to toggle the hide and show imageView, and my auto layout set to when imageView hidden the anchor move into another imageView. I use the content hugging priority programmatically in this. so here is my code, can you show me why my uiimageView not hiding.

```
// This is in my subclass of UIButton
let profileLbl = UILabel()
    let badgeImageView = UIImageView()
    let rightArrowImageView = UIImageView()

    var isHiddenBadge = false

    var visibleProfileTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var hiddenProfileTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
        configure()
    }

    init(name: String, isBadgeHidden: Bool = false) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        profileLbl.text = name
        profileLbl.font = UIFont(name: "NunitoSans-SemiBold", size: 16)
        profileLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1)
        isHiddenBadge = isBadgeHidden
        toggleHide(badge: isHiddenBadge)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func configure() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [profileLbl, badgeImageView, rightArrowImageView].forEach({ v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(v)
        })

        visibleProfileTrailingConstraint = profileLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: badgeImageView.leadingAnchor, constant: -5)
        hiddenProfileTrailingConstraint = profileLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightArrowImageView.leadingAnchor, constant: -5)

        visibleProfileTrailingConstraint.priority   = .defaultHigh
        hiddenProfileTrailingConstraint.priority    = .defaultLow

        badgeImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "warning_error 1")
        rightArrowImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic-arrow-right")
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 24),
            profileLbl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            visibleProfileTrailingConstraint,
            hiddenProfileTrailingConstraint,

            badgeImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            badgeImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            badgeImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),

            rightArrowImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -24),
            rightArrowImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            rightArrowImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
            rightArrowImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16)
        ])
    }

    private func toggleHide(badge: Bool) {

        if badge == false {

            if badgeImageView.isHidden {

                badgeImageView.isHidden = false
                visibleProfileTrailingConstraint.priority   = .defaultHigh
                hiddenProfileTrailingConstraint.priority    = .defaultLow
            }

        } else {
            visibleProfileTrailingConstraint.priority   = .defaultLow
            hiddenProfileTrailingConstraint.priority    = .defaultHigh
            badgeImageView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

// I initialise it in my viewController
let infoBtn             = GTProfileBtn(name: "Basic Info", isBadgeHidden: false)

// this is when I try to test it in my viewDidLoad
infoBtn.isHiddenBadge = true
```

Comment: You are not calling toggleHide after setting isHiddenBadge to true.

Comment: I called it in my initialiser, not in my viewDidLoad. since toggleHide I set it in private @ParagBafna

Comment: That is a problem When you are calling it in the initialiser, isHiddenBadge value is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

```
var isHiddenBadge = false {
    didSet {
        toggleHide(badge: isHiddenBadge)
    }
}
```

The problem is you not calling toggleHide after setting isHiddenBadge. The above code will solve the issue.

Comment: Hey Thank you @MuhammadSadiq it work, I thought if I only place the toggleHide inside my initialiser will work. thank you for the solution :)